# Android Parcelable Unmarshalling prob

Tags: android, arraylist, unmarshalling, parcelable

I have two class named `AlacarteCategory` and `AlacartePack`

**Class AlacartePack**

```
public class AlacartePack implements Parcelable {

    private int alacartePackId;
    private String alacartePackName;
    private double price;
    private String smsCode;// no need to pass
    private Boolean isSelected;// no need to pass

    private List<Channel> channelList;// no need to pass

    public  AlacartePack(){
        channelList = new ArrayList<Channel>();
        isSelected = false;
    }

    //// getter & setter

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int i) {
        dest.writeString(alacartePackName);
        dest.writeInt(alacartePackId);
        dest.writeDouble(price);

    }

    private AlacartePack(Parcel in){
        this.alacartePackId = in.readInt();
        this.alacartePackName = in.readString();
        this.price = in.readDouble();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<AlacartePack> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<AlacartePack>() {

        @Override
        public AlacartePack createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new AlacartePack(source);
        }

        @Override
        public AlacartePack[] newArray(int size) {
            return new AlacartePack[size];
        }
    };
}
```

**Class AlacarteCategory**

```
public class AlacarteCategory implements Parcelable {

    private int categoryId;
    private String categoryName;

    private List<AlacartePack> alacartePackList;

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public AlacarteCategory(){
        alacartePackList = new ArrayList<AlacartePack>();
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public List<AlacartePack> getAlacartePackList() {
        return alacartePackList;
    }

    public void setAlacartePackList(List<AlacartePack> alacartePackList) {
        this.alacartePackList = alacartePackList;
    }

    public void addPack(AlacartePack mAlacartePack){
        alacartePackList.add(mAlacartePack);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int i) {
        dest.writeString(categoryName);
        dest.writeInt(categoryId);
        dest.writeTypedList(alacartePackList);
    }

    private AlacarteCategory(Parcel in){
        this.categoryId = in.readInt();
        this.categoryName = in.readString();
        this.alacartePackList = in.readArrayList(AlacartePack.class.getClassLoader());
        //in.readTypedList(alacartePackList,AlacartePack.CREATOR);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<AlacarteCategory> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<AlacarteCategory>() {

        @Override
        public AlacarteCategory createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new AlacarteCategory(source);
        }

        @Override
        public AlacarteCategory[] newArray(int size) {
            return new AlacarteCategory[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Now I want to pass a ArrayList of AlacarteCategory with my intent. It is giving Unmarshalling problem:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Dishtv.Dynamic/dishtv.dynamic.RechargePaymentActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@b5903448: Unmarshalling unknown type code 4980781 at offset 152
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@b5903448: Unmarshalling unknown type code 4980781 at offset 152
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1921)
            at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2103)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1544)
            at dishtv.dynamic.model.AlacarteCategory.<init>(AlacarteCategory.java:66)
            at dishtv.dynamic.model.AlacarteCategory.<init>(AlacarteCategory.java:12)
            at dishtv.dynamic.model.AlacarteCategory$1.createFromParcel(AlacarteCategory.java:74)
            at dishtv.dynamic.model.AlacarteCategory$1.createFromParcel(AlacarteCategory.java:70)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:1992)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1854)
            at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2103)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1544)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1875)
            at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2094)
            at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
            at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1048)
            at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:3923)
            at dishtv.dynamic.RechargePaymentActivity.onCreate(RechargePaymentActivity.java:52)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

What is problem in my code?

Comment: is `in.readTypedList(alacartePackList,AlacartePack.CREATOR);` in `AlacarteCategory.java` not working?

Comment: it was giving java.lang.NullPointerException. That is why I changed the same.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the cause of the exception, I would figure out how to solve the NullPointer

Comment: Please help to find out the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are writing and reading in different order.

For example, for `AlacartePack` class the method `writeToParcel` is ok:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int i) {
    dest.writeString(alacartePackName);
    dest.writeInt(alacartePackId);
    dest.writeDouble(price);

}
```

But the constructor should be:

```
private AlacartePack(Parcel in){
    this.alacartePackName = in.readString();
    this.alacartePackId = in.readInt();
    this.price = in.readDouble();
}
```

The same applies to your `AlacarteCategory` class.

In addition to this, you should fix the way you are reading your list in `AlacarteCategory`. Something like this:

```
private AlacarteCategory(Parcel in){
    this.categoryName = in.readString();
    this.categoryId = in.readInt();
    this.alacartePackList = new ArrayList<AlacartePack>();
    in.readList(this.alacartePackList, AlacarteCategory.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

And just write it as a list as follows:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int i) {
    dest.writeString(categoryName);
    dest.writeInt(categoryId);
    dest.writeList(alacartePackList);
}
```

Comment: Thank you to help me finding the problem.